# Python 3.4.3 Aligning Columns

Tags: python

How would I align the aList (the Letters) with the columns? Also if I increased the columns to a lower or higher amount how would I adjust the aList that if a user inputs a certain number of columns the letters will align with the rest of the grid?

```
aList = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
bList = len(aList)
grid = []
aWidth = 10
aHeight = 10

def garden(grid):
    for j in range(0, bList):
        print(" ", aList[j], end = '')
    print( )

    for i in range(aWidth):
        if i+1 < 10:
            print(i+1, '', end=' ')
        else:
            print(i+1, end=' ')
        for j in range(aHeight):
                print('- ', end=' ')  
        else:
            print('\n',end='')

#Main            
garden(grid)
```

Output is this

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
1  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
2  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
3  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
4  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
5  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
6  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
7  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
8  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
9  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
10 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
```

Desired output

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
1  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
2  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
3  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
4  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
5  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
6  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
7  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
8  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
9  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  
10 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
```

Thank you to any replies that can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [`str.center()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.center) function to make the data come in center of a fixed width, and also specify a static column width, so that all columns are that big?

Demo -

```
aList = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
bList = len(aList)
grid = []
aWidth = 10
aHeight = 10

def garden(grid):
    colWidth=5
    print(" "*colWidth,end='') #This is needed as first column does not have a title.
    for j in range(0, bList):
        print(aList[j].center(colWidth), end = '')
    print( )
    for i in range(aWidth):
        if i+1 < 10:
            print(str(i+1).center(colWidth), end='')
        else:
            print(str(i+1).center(colWidth), end='')
        for j in range(aHeight):
                print('-'.center(colWidth), end='')  
        else:
            print('\n',end='')

#Main            
garden(grid)
```

Result -

```
       A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
  1    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -
  2    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -
  3    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -
  4    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -
  5    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -
  6    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -
  7    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -
  8    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -
  9    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -
  10   -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -    -
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a column to be a certain width, string.format can help. If you want a variable to be put in a column a certain width, just do:

```
'{:3}'.format(22)
#' 22'
```

If you want to make it left aligned, just add a '<', e.g.:

```
'{:<3}'.formatt(22)
#'22 '
```